# How to test iccTransmitApduBasicChannel API?

Tags: android

I tested new APIs for Android(Lollipop 5.1) Carrrier Service.
I tested it using Nexus 5.

iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel is working well.
but  iccTransmitApduBasicChannel is not working and always return "6F00" error.

How can i do to work well?

Below is my funtion.

```
    public String sendCommandToICCcard(String command, boolean isBasicChannel)
    {
        int cla, ins, p1, p2, p3;
        String data;
        if(tm != null)
        {
            cla = Integer.parseInt(command.substring(0,2), 16);
            ins = Integer.parseInt(command.substring(2,4), 16);
            p1 = Integer.parseInt(command.substring(4,6), 16);
            p2 = Integer.parseInt(command.substring(6,8), 16);
            p3 = Integer.parseInt(command.substring(8, 10), 16);
            data = command.substring(10);

            if(isBasicChannel)
            {
                Log.d("sendCommandToICCcard", "Basic channel");
                return tm.iccTransmitApduBasicChannel(cla, ins, p1, p2, p3, data);
            }
            else
            {
                String sResp = null;
                Log.d("sendCommandToICCcard", "Logical channel");
                IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse resp = tm.iccOpenLogicalChannel("333333333333");
                int channel = resp.getChannel();

                if(channel>0)
                {
                    sResp = tm.iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel(channel, cla, ins, p1, p2, p3, data);
                    if(sResp.length() == 4 && sResp.substring(0,2).equalsIgnoreCase("61"))
                    {
                        ins = 0xC0;
                        p3 = 0x00;
                        data = null;
                        sResp = tm.iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel(channel, cla, ins, p1, p2, p3, data);
                    }

                    tm.iccCloseLogicalChannel(channel);
                }

                return sResp;

}
        }
        else
        return "TelephonyManager object is null!";
        }

        }
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Also, how did you pick the aid for the channel?

Answer (score 0):

BasicChannel is often protected by the UICC. You need to work with the UICC provider to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Nexus 5 doesn't have a proper RILD in order to communicate with the UICC. You'll need to use a newer device, like Nexus 5X.